# How to display image with this html and jquery code

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display an image but with code like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:" class="menuin" from="account.png"></a>
<a href="javascript:" class="menuin" from="home.png"></a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".menuin").html('<img src="img/'+$(this).attr('from')+'">');
```

I have a trouble on jquery code. I think that is wrong code. I want to display an image according to **from** attribute. can you help me please?

Comment: `.html` takes a callback function as it's parameter - see @Satpal's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`.html(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/Html/#html-function) method, it will iterate `.menuin` elements and use current element context i.e. `this` to get the relevant attribute value.

I would also recommend to use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes.

```js
$(".menuin").html(function(index, oldHtml) {
  return '<img src="img/' + $(this).data('from') + '">'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:" class="menuin" data-from="account.png"></a>
<a href="javascript:" class="menuin" data-from="home.png"></a>
```